# Returning values from remote Python script

Tags: java, python, ssh, remote-access, jsch

I am calling a remote Python script from local Java code via JSch.
When I execute an "ls" from Java on the Python box, it returns the correct result (connection works). I then wrote a small program that returned the string "hello world". On the Java side, the result comes in as blank. In general, if something is outputted on the terminal, it is returned but variables are not returned.

Java code:

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class SSHManager
{
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SSHManager.class.getName());
private JSch jschSSHChannel;
private String strUserName;
private String strConnectionIP;
private int intConnectionPort;
private String strPassword;
private Session sesConnection;
private int intTimeOut;

private void doCommonConstructorActions(String userName, String password,
        String connectionIP, String knownHostsFileName)
{
    jschSSHChannel = new JSch();

    try
    {
        jschSSHChannel.setKnownHosts(knownHostsFileName);
    }
    catch(JSchException jschX)
    {
        logError(jschX.getMessage());
    }

    strUserName = userName;
    strPassword = password;
    strConnectionIP = connectionIP;
}

public SSHManager(String userName, String password, 
        String connectionIP, String knownHostsFileName)
{
    doCommonConstructorActions(userName, password, 
            connectionIP, knownHostsFileName);
    intConnectionPort = 22;
    intTimeOut = 60000;
}

public SSHManager(String userName, String password, String connectionIP, 
        String knownHostsFileName, int connectionPort)
{
    doCommonConstructorActions(userName, password, connectionIP, 
            knownHostsFileName);
    intConnectionPort = connectionPort;
    intTimeOut = 60000;
}

public SSHManager(String userName, String password, String connectionIP, 
        String knownHostsFileName, int connectionPort, int timeOutMilliseconds)
{
    doCommonConstructorActions(userName, password, connectionIP, 
            knownHostsFileName);
    intConnectionPort = connectionPort;
    intTimeOut = timeOutMilliseconds;
}

public String connect()
{
    String errorMessage = null;

    try
    {
        sesConnection = jschSSHChannel.getSession(strUserName, 
                strConnectionIP, intConnectionPort);
        sesConnection.setPassword(strPassword);
        // UNCOMMENT THIS FOR TESTING PURPOSES, BUT DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION
        // sesConnection.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        sesConnection.setConfig(config);

        sesConnection.connect(intTimeOut);
    }
    catch(JSchException jschX)
    {
        System.out.println("Connection failed.");
        errorMessage = jschX.getMessage();
    }

    return errorMessage;
}

private String logError(String errorMessage)
{
    if(errorMessage != null)
    {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "{0}:{1} - {2}", 
                new Object[]{strConnectionIP, intConnectionPort, errorMessage});
    }

    return errorMessage;
}

private String logWarning(String warnMessage)
{
    if(warnMessage != null)
    {
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "{0}:{1} - {2}", 
                new Object[]{strConnectionIP, intConnectionPort, warnMessage});
    }

    return warnMessage;
}

public String sendCommand(String command)
{
    StringBuilder outputBuffer = new StringBuilder();

    try
    {
        Channel channel = sesConnection.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
        channel.connect();
        InputStream commandOutput = channel.getInputStream();
        int readByte = commandOutput.read();

        while(readByte != 0xffffffff)
        {
            outputBuffer.append((char)readByte);
            readByte = commandOutput.read();
        }

        channel.disconnect();
    }
    catch(IOException ioX)
    {
        logWarning(ioX.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    catch(JSchException jschX)
    {
        logWarning(jschX.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    return outputBuffer.toString();
}

public void close()
{
    sesConnection.disconnect();
}
}
```

Test code:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SSHManagerTest {
/**
 * Test of sendCommand method, of class SSHManager.
 */
@Test
public void testSendCommand()
{
    System.out.println("sendCommand");

    String command = "python /home/abc/helloworld.py";
    String userName = "abc";
    String password = "pqr";
    String connectionIP = "10.112.1.2";
    SSHManager instance = new SSHManager(userName, password, connectionIP, "");
    String errorMessage = instance.connect();

    if(errorMessage != null)
    {
        System.out.println(errorMessage);
        fail();
    }

    //String expResult = "thisOne\n";
    // call sendCommand for each command and the output 
    //(without prompts) is returned
    String result = instance.sendCommand(command);
    System.out.println(result + " (expected hello world)");
    // close only after all commands are sent
    instance.close();
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
}
}
```

Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def main():
    return "Hello world"
```

Comment: The problem isn't with the SSH code. Did you try running the Python code locally (on your local machine, without SSH)?

Comment: Yes, do check the comment on mhawke's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def main():
    return "Hello world"
```

Does not produce any output to stdout, i.e. `return` simply returns a value, it does not print it on stdout. You can try this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def main():
    print("Hello world")
```

Note that I also changed the "shebang" to use `env`. This is generally a more reliable way to invoke python as it avoids pathing issues.

Comment: I _want_ to return values to java, not print to stdout. I'm sorry if my question implies something else. I mentioned stdout just to state that the connection works fine.

Comment: @Natasha Programs don't return anything, except for exit codes (which are single-byte numbers, and still SSH doesn't send those to the client).

Comment: Well, you can't return a string via SSH like that. You mentioned running `ls` remotely as a test - that outputs to stdout. Is there a reason that you can't collect the stdout of the remote process and use that?

Comment: Ok my approach probably is wrong then, let me describe my problem. My java code will call Python scripts on a remote box. This Python script in turn carries out certain operations and returns multiple IDs in JSON format. I need to get these IDs back to java.

Comment: Just write the ID on the remote process's stdout and read it in your Java code. That is what is already happening in your java function `sendCommand()` - it returns the output of the remote command as a string.

Comment: Will  the following work? 1) I need to send input too. 2) The output will come as JSON, will displaying it work?

Comment: @Natasha: You could try it and see if it works :) 1) To send input you might need to call [`getOutputStream()`](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#getOutputStream%28%29) and write data to the returned object. 2) JSON is a string, so no problem with displaying it, although, you need to parse it in order to use it.